# Kivy : how to get widget by id (without kv)

Tags: python, widget, kivy

Let's say I define on the fly in Kivy a few widgets (buttons) and dynamically assign their id.
I'm not using kv language in this use case.
I can keep a reference of a widget id without keeping track of the widget itself : then I'd like to access the widget through its id.
Can I do something like "get widget by id" ?
(If I had defined the widget in a kv file, I could have used self.ids.the_widget_id to access the widget itself through its id)

Comment: Why would you want to look it up every time rather than saving a reference? If you're creating the widgets yourself in Python, it's your job to keep track of them. Use a `dict` yourself if you want to map names to widgets.

Comment: I see, that's an approach

Comment: I kind of expected that this dict could have been managed by kivy itself, meaning that the look-up induced by "get widget by id" would have been kept light.

Comment: IDs in Kivy aren't the same as IDs in HTML/JS. IDs are not globally unique - they are unique to a given rule. This is because you might create `MyWidget` which contains `SubWidget` with `id`=`sub`. Then you might create multiple `MyWidget`s which would duplicate that ID.

Comment: `dict` lookups are fast. The rule ID maps used by Kivy are just `dict`s anyway. The lookup will be just as light as you were expecting if you implement your own `dict`. Walking the tree, as suggested by Nykakin, will work but will be magnitudes of order slower.

Answer (score 3):

Kivy widgets make tree structure. Children of any widget are avaiable through `children` atribute. If you want, you can keep reference only to root window and then iterate over it's widgets using `walk` method:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button 

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        button = Button(text="...", id="1")
        button.bind(on_release=self.print_label)

        l1 = BoxLayout(id="2")
        l2 = BoxLayout(id="3")

        self.add_widget(l1)
        l1.add_widget(l2)             
        l2.add_widget(button)

    def print_label(self, *args):
        for widget in self.walk():
            print("{} -> {}".format(widget, widget.id))

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

`walk()` and `walk_reverse()` method were added to `kivy.uix.widget.Widget` in 1.8.1 version of Kivy. For older versions you need to recursively parse tree yourself:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button 

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        button = Button(text="...", id="1")
        button.bind(on_release=self.print_label)

        l1 = BoxLayout(id="2")
        l2 = BoxLayout(id="3")

        self.add_widget(l1)
        l1.add_widget(l2)             
        l2.add_widget(button)

    def print_label(self, *args):
        children = self.children[:]
        while children:
            child = children.pop()
            print("{} -> {}".format(child, child.id))
            children.extend(child.children)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the widget using directly the ids. For example in your code you can modify the Button text with the following snippet:

```
self.ids.2.ids.3.ids.1.text = '!!!!'
```

Comment: why kivy not have querySelector like js?

Answer (score 0):

You can change properties of each widget using ids:

```
self.ids['order_number'].text='S1212'
```

Comment: As someone new to kivy, I would like to know further why this answer was downvoted. Is this because in general, the program should only locally know about the widgets it needs to know about, or is it because `self` is more akin to `root` in this example. Any further details?