# kivy access child id

Tags: python, kivy

I want to access the id of the child to decide whether to delete the widget or not. I have the following code:

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Terminator(BoxLayout):
    def DelButton(self):
        print("Deleting...")

        for child in self.children:
            print(child)
            print(child.text)

            if not child.id == 'deleto':
                print(child.id)
                #self.remove_widget(child)
            else:
                print('No delete')


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<Terminator>:
    id: masta
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Button:
        id: deleto
        text: "Delete"
        on_release: masta.DelButton()

    Button
    Button

Terminator
```

However when printing the id with: `print(child.id)`, it always returns: `None`. Even though `print(child.text)` correct returns `Delete` or  .

### Question

- Why does `child.id` not return `deleto`, but instead `None`?
- How can I make a check that I don't delete the button with "Delete" on it, but delete all other buttons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can read in the [documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets):

> In a widget tree there is often a need to access/reference other
>   widgets. The Kv Language provides a way to do this using id’s. Think
>   of them as class level variables that can only be used in the Kv
>   language.

Accesing ids from Python code is described [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code). Working example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string("""
<Terminator>:
    id: masta
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MyButton:
        id: deleto

        button_id: deleto

        text: "Delete"
        on_release: masta.DelButton()

    MyButton
    MyButton
""")

class MyButton(Button):
    button_id = ObjectProperty(None)

class Terminator(BoxLayout):
    def DelButton(self):
        for child in self.children:
            print(child.button_id)       

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Terminator()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

To skip deleting a button with "Delete" label you can examine its `text` property. Hovewer deleting from inside the loop will lead to the bugs, since some of the children will get skiped after the list you're iterating on will get altered:

```
class Terminator(BoxLayout):
    def DelButton(self):
        for child in self.children:            
            self.remove_widget(child) # this will leave one child
```

You have to create a list of children to delete:

```
class Terminator(BoxLayout):
    def DelButton(self):
        for child in [child for child in self.children]:            
            self.remove_widget(child) # this will delete all children
```

In your case:

```
class Terminator(BoxLayout):
    def DelButton(self):
        for child in [child for child in self.children if child.text != "Delete"]:            
            self.remove_widget(child)
```

Comment: Thanks :) I was thinking about using the text as well, but it didn't seem like a robust way and I thought there must be a different way. I didn't know about the bugs of deleting while looping over the children, so that was useful. However is creating a button_id not a bit pointless? because `print(child)` gives the same as `print(child.button_id)`. It both gives a <__main__.MyButton object instead of 'deleto'.

Comment: In this case, yes, because you're looping over the `children` array. Imagine if you move `button_id: deleto` one level up, to the `Terminator` description - then you could remove button with id `deleto` in `DelButton` method using a single line `self.remove_widget(self.button_id)` instead of lookin for that particular button in `children` array.

Comment: Somewhere else (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27779370/3399066) I saw `children = MyWidget.children[:]` *next line* `while children:` *next line* `child = children.pop()`. Is this method better, just different or worse than `for child in self.children:`?

Comment: In the example you provided, OP is creating a stack because he want to extend it with children of the every child and traverse the entire tree recursively. It's basically [non-recursive depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode) of a tree. There isn't really a need to do that since you can use [walk](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.walk) method instead.

Answer (score 0):

The above are good options for implementing the task.  I've used them quite successfully in my code.  Now I want to recommend the visual code that the Kivy Framework directly recommends in its documentation.
Look at it, it is clear and available at this link:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.ids

You can quickly figure it out and use it.
This section is - Widget class, anchor is - ids.

This is a dictionary of ids defined in your kv language. This will only be populated if you use ids in your kv language code.

ids is a DictProperty and defaults to an empty dict {}.

The ids are populated for each root level widget definition. For example:

```
# in kv
<MyWidget@Widget>:
    id: my_widget
    Label:
        id: label_widget
        Widget:
            id: inner_widget
            Label:
                id: inner_label
    TextInput:
        id: text_input
    OtherWidget:
        id: other_widget


<OtherWidget@Widget>
    id: other_widget
    Label:
        id: other_label
        TextInput:
            id: other_textinput





# Then, in python:

>>> widget = MyWidget()
>>> print(widget.ids)
{'other_widget': <weakproxy at 041CFED0 to OtherWidget at 041BEC38>,
'inner_widget': <weakproxy at 04137EA0 to Widget at 04138228>,
'inner_label': <weakproxy at 04143540 to Label at 04138260>,
'label_widget': <weakproxy at 04137B70 to Label at 040F97A0>,
'text_input': <weakproxy at 041BB5D0 to TextInput at 041BEC00>}

>>> print(widget.ids['other_widget'].ids)
{'other_textinput': <weakproxy at 041DBB40 to TextInput at 041BEF48>,
'other_label': <weakproxy at 041DB570 to Label at 041BEEA0>}
>>> print(widget.ids['label_widget'].ids)
{}
```